# How to turn off internal laptop speakers when external speakers / headphones are connected in Elementary OS?

Tags: audio, elementary-os

In the eOS settings I see no option to make internal speakers turn off when the external jack is connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [`gnome-alsamixer`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-alsamixer/) and a specific option is there: "Headphone Jack Sense".

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to make this permanent?